# Динамический вывод доступных вариантов в поле ввода HTML, JS, PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Подскажите, как реализовать такую вещь. Имеется поле для ввода в форме. Надо, чтобы по мере ввода текста в это поле, в виде выпадающего списка подсказок выводились из MySQL базы только те записи, которые соотвествуют уже введенному тексту.

Answer (score 3):

Это называется подсказки(suggests или autocomplete), вкратце нужно отправлять запрос на сервер с уже введенными данными, сервер же должен вернуть список подходящих значений. Реализация зависит от деталей, если вы ищете готовое решение то существует несколько библиотек для js. Как пример: [раз](https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html), [два](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Подобрать подходящую библиотеку вы сможете только сами исходя из ваших требований.

Comment: Спасибо, @Torv, как раз то, что я искал. Я так понимаю, если БД небольшая, то проще сразу выгрузить все варианты в виде переменных в js код внутри самой страницы, чем каждый раз привводе нового символа обращаться к MySQL?

Comment: @СергейГринев Если совсем мало, то да, это может быть лучше. Но это если мы говорим о десятках и сотнях значений, на тысячах страница для всех пользователей будет загружаться медленнее, и, в зависимости от качества js библиотеки, при поиске пользователи на медленных компьютерах могут испытывать неудобства.